# Find Average of salary in ORCHARD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Friends

I  Am Beginner  with ORCHARD. I  Want to find Average  Salary of Employees  And Top 4      Employees With Max  Average Salary .I Don't Know how to find average in orchard and Fetch 4 Employees with Max average  Salary  .

Please  Help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Firts of all, ORCHARD is an CMS developed in ASP.NET MVC.

What you are asking, is how to do a query to a database.

Using LINQ to EntityFramework you can do the following to get AVERAGE of SALARY taking into account all your Employees:

```
YourContext.Employees.Average(w => w.Salary);
```

For the 4 Employees with higher salary you can do:

```
YourContext.Employees.OrderByDescending(w => w.Salary).Take(4);
```

Don't know if you use EntityFramework, but if you use LINQ the idea is the same.

Comment: Yes, i am asking database query.   i have query Services.ContentManager.Query<EmployeePart, EmployeePartRecord>().ToList();.But there is no Average or sum function. i  am asking how i get average or sum with above query.infact i can get all record from table using this query.and i want to know how can i use jion with this query.

Comment: As all the LINQ methods are extensions, you need to have references to LINQ namespaces to this to work. If you remove the ".ToList()" what tape is the return of that query?

Comment: Thanks Friend for help. i find solution for this problem i simple use var empData=Services.ContentManager.Query<EmployeePart, EmployeePartRecord>().ToList(); and after that i can simple write query like linq and apply linq function as var data=from x in empData.....